# With threading.Lock() not working properly

Tags: python-3.x

I am retrieving a list of classes from a "function_list" that executes against routing devices. I've noticed when I started to play with a couple of classes, the seperate log files for each class tend to not write out properly due to connecting and executing against the devices is parallel (basically it's running too fast). For the most part everything is fine, but there is a hiccup here or there, consistently and its obvious it's due to threading (i.e I can put a time.sleep() and it works).

I tried locking the variables passed to each class to make the connection happen. It's obviously not the issue, but I've tried locking a few places in the below code and can't get it to work properly. Any tips for locking...?

Here's the code below.

```
def looper():
while not thread_pool.empty():
    global lock

    conn = thread_pool.get()
    host = ip_pool.get()

    for i in function_list:
        print("This is i inside Looper")
        print(i)
        with lock:
            res = threading.Thread(target=i, args=(conn, host), daemon=True)
            res.start()
            thread_list.append(res)

    for i in thread_list:
        i.join()
        print("This is the threads list")
        print(i.__repr__())
```

per comment suggetion below, I've updated the code. I tried to use a global lock on the functions inside functions_list, which is where the problem is:  each function inside that list connects to a router and runs some commands. This is where I think the issue is happening and so I need to implement proper locking. I tried lock.acquire inside this statement and it froze:

```
for i in function_list:
        lock.acquire()
        print("This is i inside Looper")
        print(i)
```

I tried splitting  dynamically created threads lists (based on function name) and joining the threads inside, it seemed to write out even less than before.  The "i" function below is what I need to have executed before it is interrupted by another function using the same connection variables (conn and host).

```
res = threading.Thread(target=i, args=(conn, host), daemon=True)
```

Comment: The lock usage you show doesn't make any sense, since no other code can access your `lock` local variable. Presumably the locking you want should be around the parts of your functions (in `function_list`) that do the stuff that's conflicting if you don't do any locking. Without seeing any of that code, I'm not sure we can help you.

Comment: Yes, it should be around the functions, because these are being what's threaded. I will post some updated code below.

Comment: Your edited code doesn't make sense either - you need to do your locking *inside the target functions*, around whatever specific parts of those functions need mutual exclusion. Not inside `looper`.

Comment: (Also, `thread_pool` is a bizarre name for what is clearly not a thread pool.)

Comment: user2357112
Ok thanks I see what you're saying. Also I wrote that as a reminder to myself for what i was supposed to do with it later.